# How to get a list of dates in Pervasive SQL

Tags: recursive-query, pervasive, actian

Our time & attendance database is a Pervasive/Actian Zen database. What I'm trying to do is create a query that just lists the next 14 days from today. I'll then cross apply this list of dates with employee records so that in effect I have a list of people/dates for the next 14 days.

I've done it with a recursive CTE on SQL server quite easily. I could also do it with a loop in SQL Server too but I can't figure it out with Pervasive SQL. Loops can only exist within Stored Procedures and triggers.

Looking around I thought that this code that I found and adapted might work, but it doesn't (and further research suggests that there isn't a recursive option within Pervasive at all.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_numbers(n, xDate) 
AS (
     SELECT 
           0, CURDATE() + 1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     n+1, 
     dateAdd(day,n,xDate) 
    FROM 
     cte_numbers 
    WHERE n < 14
)
SELECT 
     xDate 
FROM 
cte_numbers;
```

I just wondered whether anyone could help me write an SQL query that gives me this list of dates, outside of a stored procedure.

Comment: You wanted to create a (temp) table with the next 14 days, but a one time generation of a bigger table (and filtering) does do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dates(d DATE PRIMARY KEY, x INTEGER);
```

And create a first record like this:

```
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-01-01',0);
```

Then you can use this statement which **doubles** the number of records in the table `dates`, every time it is executed. (so you need to run it a couple of times

When you run it 10 times the table `dates` will have 21 oktober 2023 as last date.
When you run it 12 times the last date will be 19 march 2032.

```
INSERT INTO dates 
   SELECT 
      DATEADD(DAY,m.m+1,d),
      x+m.m+1 
   from dates
   cross join (select max(x) m from dates) m
   order by d;
```

Of course the column `x` can be deleted (optionally) with next statement, but you cannot add more records using the previous statement:

```
ALTER TABLE dates DROP COLUMN x;
```

Finally, to return the next 14 day from today:

```
SELECT d 
FROM DATES 
WHERE d BETWEEN CURDATE( ) AND DATEADD(DAY,13,CURDATE());
```